# Build-process stops because of bumping CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION using "agvtool bump"

Tags: ios, xcode, versioning

I am trying to bump the CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION before building a xcode project but the build process gets cancelled every time.

If I set the target to an iOS Simulator it bumps, builds and starts the app as intended.

If a real iDevice is attached and chosen as the target, the build process gets cancelled after bumping.

Anyone know a solution or an alternative way for this?